# Printing Large image

Tags: printing, photos

I have a large image (~23.6 X ~26.7) inches and i would like to print it out. It's not important that it goes on photo paper, just that it can be assembled into a single unit after printing. What tools and/or techniques do you recommend for printing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the site [Blockposters](http://www.blockposters.com/default.aspx) which can take in large pictures and spread it across multiple pages.  Simply upload a picture, download a pdf then print it out and some selotape later you have a large picture.

Comment: I ended up going with this, though the printed item has borders which may impede my progress... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**[Poster Printer](http://posterprinter.sourceforge.net/)** works with your existing printer to allow you to print documents at a much larger size than would fit on a single printed page

[image]

(open source, Windows)

Comment: +1 Cool, I'd been looking for something like that ages ago and all I found was the website I linked in my answer... It even has cutting guides and overlap!  Excellent find Molly, thanks!

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As well as blockposters that Mokubai linked to there is [Rasterbater](http://homokaasu.org/rasterbator/) which does much the same thing but produces half-toned images rather than solid colour ones. Depending on the image you select this can produce results that are more pleasing to the eye ("jaggies" from enlargement are less obvious) while saving ink/toner.

Some printer drivers support poster-print like this themselves. The drivers for my last couple of inkjets did (the last one bought ~4 years ago) as do the ones for my current colour laser. If your driver does support poster print then it has the advantage of working on *any* output, not just an image, so you can print posters directly from anything such as a DTP app or word processor. Support in drives tends to be have more limited flexibility, in terms of range of page multiples they support, than external utilities though.

Virtual printer drivers often support this to so can add support to any printer that doens't have it already. [Fineprint](http://www.fineprint.com/) is one I've used (though mainly for its booklet printing rather than poster) with success in the past, before I had printers with drivers with the features built in. Fineprint isn't free, or cheap if you only intent to use it a few times, but you might find cheaper or F/OSS equivalents if you search for "virtual printer driver" or such.

Answer (score 0):

The best result will be achieved if you get it printed on a large format printer.

You can get that at a local copy shop, or order the print online.

Comment: This might be doable at some point, though for now i'd like something that works at home